# Openshift 3 - Build stuck in pending state

Tags: node.js, deployment, build, openshift, openshift-3

I have been using Openshift 3 seamlessly to build and deploy a Node.js application for several months.

Since yesterday, new builds of the same app systematically fail because they are stuck forever in the Pending state, with the "Started status: *not started*" until after an hour when the build fails with "No logs available".

[image: Build stuck in pending state]

Has anyone else had this issue?
I am using *starter-us-east-1* (no mention of it in [status.starter.openshift.com](https://status.starter.openshift.com/)).

My app runs fine locally and I don't understand what's the issue with Openshift.
Deployment of existing builds seems to work, but there's no way to make new builds, either manually or via webhooks.
I didn't change anything in the configuration, just my code.

Thank you by advance for any hint.

- Additional info: The issue doesn't occur in *starter-ca-central-1* where I can see a whole new interface with notifications, and the build of the app I have there works fine.
- More info: The new interface has been rolled out to *starter-us-east-1*, but the problem is still more present than ever. Here is a screenshot of my Pods/Events tab:
  [image: 0 nodes available - Pod failed scheduling]

Comment: Welcome to the club. It's an Openshift problem.  It's been going on for weeks.  You will just have to wait it out like the rest of us.  Good luck: )

Comment: I see. I saw your question but for some reason thought you had an issue with deployment and not only the build. I really want to switch my old app to the other "location" that looks modern and works well, but I think there's no way I can do this! This should have been fixed... Ongoing for weeks? Come on RedHat.

Comment: Yes it's frustrating.  I wish they had it sorted out before they took the Openshift 2 apps offline.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Openshift: No nodes are available that match all of the following predicates:: Insufficient cpu (173), MatchNodeSelector (5)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47260594/openshift-no-nodes-are-available-that-match-all-of-the-following-predicates-i)