# Openshift Origin error: Insufficient cpu

Tags: openshift-origin

I am using OpenShift Origin starter package for a node.js application. For the last 5 days no pod is starting up saying the following error in events:

> No nodes are available that match all of the following predicates::
>   Insufficient cpu (173), MatchNodeSelector (5).

I tried to fix the error but failing to fix that, I deleted the entire application and tried to build again but still shows the same error. How can I fix this?

Comment: This is very interesting. I started getting the same error in my application just two days ago, but it worked fine for about a month before then. It is good to know I am not the only one experiencing this.

Comment: @NobleMushtak, what do I say, I keep trying, keep deleting, nothing's working out. The error slightly changed now though. It became Insufficient cpu (175) from (173).

Comment: Try looking [at this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47262209/3740708). Basically, I think this means Openshift is having a problem with not having enough computers to handle everyone's apps, so there's nothing we can really do.

Comment: @NobleMushtak, ya looks like it. So, what else can I do, just trying to shift into heroku.