# not able to build or deploy in openshift wildfly project event coming as Failed scheduling

Tags: java, openshift, wildfly, openshift-3

not able to build or deploy in openshift wildfly project event coming

No nodes are available that match all of the following predicates:: Insufficient cpu (106), Insufficient memory (150), MatchNodeSelector (5).

[image: error]

Space is not a constraint as i have deleted all the present projects

Comment: I also started getting a similar error two days ago, except I have just "No nodes are available that match all of the following predicates:: Insufficient cpu (175), MatchNodeSelector (5)."

Comment: I think what is happening to you is very similar [to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47262209/3740708).

Comment: from @Graham Dumpleton You should always check status.starter.openshift.com That indicates there is a known outage on us-west-1 today. –

Comment: @Noble Mushtak  is it resolved ? for you

Comment: No, the outage in us-west-1 is still ongoing, so I am still getting the error.

Comment: having issue with my app deployment too. status page shows no outage.